# creating key usage Off-line CRL Signing in Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, x509certificate, bouncycastle

How can I create key usage Off-line CRL Signing by bouncy casle?
I know how to create predefined keyCertSign or other using constants...

```
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.KeyUsage;
KeyUsage keyUsage = new KeyUsage(KeyUsage.keyCertSign | KeyUsage.cRLSign);
```

Answer (score 3):

The KeyUsage.cRLSign should cover both CRL Signing and offline CRL Signing.  According to the X.509 spec [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.3) there are only 9 basic key usages.

```
      KeyUsage ::= BIT STRING {
       digitalSignature        (0),
       nonRepudiation          (1), -- recent editions of X.509 have
                            -- renamed this bit to contentCommitment
       keyEncipherment         (2),
       dataEncipherment        (3),
       keyAgreement            (4),
       keyCertSign             (5),
       cRLSign                 (6),
       encipherOnly            (7),
       decipherOnly            (8) }
```

If the cRLSign bit is set, and you open up the cert in IE, you will see "Off-line CRL Signing, CRL Signing".  Other certificate viewers may just say "CRL Signing".